# How can I scroll to a specific section of the html page as I open the html file?

Tags: java, html

I have a html file with usage instructions. I call it using

```
File htmlFile = new File("Usage.html");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
```

This opens the html file using my default browser, but I want it to scroll to a specific section.
I do that in html by referencing the id `<a href="#how-to-use">`, but is it possible to scroll to the section as the file is opened from my program?

Comment: is that html file yours??can you edit it?

Comment: @FastSnail Yes, it is mine.

Comment: you can open url from server like www.google.com#tar1 but not local files like example.html#tar1 so can you use localhost ?? if you want to open it in local without server then read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Selenium` to do this

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file:///D:/Usage.html"); // path can be different in your computer

WebElement href = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href*='how-to-use']"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(href).build().performe();
```

This will open the html file in chrome browser (can be changed if you like) and scroll to the element in `moveToElement`.

Answer (score 2):

> **Notice:**
>   This answer doesn't work when using Windows, Windows strips the # and remaining characters when it opens a program using default programs, this is something that should be fixed by Windows and it doesn't occur on Linux, [related OpenJDK bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7073184).

You can append the hash manually to the url:

```java
URI uri = htmlFile.toURI();
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(
        uri.getScheme(), 
        uri.getUserInfo(), 
        uri.getHost(), 
        uri.getPort(), 
        uri.getPath(), 
        uri.getQuery(), 
        "how-to-use"));
```

We cannot use a simple + operation since we have a URI object, URI doesn't have a set component method.

Comment: Hmm this isn't working for me, it doesn't scroll to the specified section.

Comment: @I_Cee I was wrong with my testing, it is a Windows only bug, all programs have it. It works correctly on Linux, but Windows strips the # and remaining when opening the default program for File urls.

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering why it still isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if above answer doesn't work ,

you can open url with hash/parameters but url shouldn't be local.
for example

`www.google.com#tar1` will work but

`example.html#tar1` doesn't work [local host]

so if you want to open local url with hashtag ,how is the alternative way?.

first write html page to another local file but add this code line.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ,URL=editedfileurl">
```

so now you can launch edit file instead of original file .then edited file will refresh with hash tag,hence will scroll to required anchor  tag.

Comment: This only works with Firefox and Internet Explorer btw. It is able to achieve what I want but it would keep bringing the user to that particular section, which is not very ideal.

Comment: @Csh what you don't want to bring the perticular section ?i think it's unclear to me.

Comment: I only need it to go to the section when the user clicks on a certain button. For other times, when the user wants to read the html file, it should just load normally and not auto scroll to the anchor tag.

Comment: @Csh so you should edit html file only certain time.for outher times just open original one